# How to ask a question in a modest way?

Tags: writing-style

> I am bold to ask you another question: is there a book written on
>   Churchill’s life? (self-made)

I wrote this sentence in an email to my foreign friend. I doubt that the use of “bold” is awkward. It does not carry the connotation of my being humble. As a Chinese saying goes, excess is not better than deficiency. To say that asking this question is bold is excessive. I desperately want to know the appropriately modest way of asking this question.

Comment: What nationality is your friend? If he/she is European or American, I can confidently assure you that your request would be seen as being very polite.

Comment: A book about somebody's life is usually called **a biography**, if it is written by the same subject, i.e that same person, then it is **an autobiography**.

Comment: An easy way to ask a question politely is to start with, "May I ask,...?" Your use of "bold" here has the effect of already imparting humility.

Comment: 1- "I am bold to ask you..." is just not the way to say it. 2 - It is extremely counterintuitive (in American society) to be modest  or overly polite when asking a general information question. "May I be so bold as to inquire what movies are playing tonight?". If you're asking the theater box office, it's their job to answer.

Comment: Dear user51369, you still haven't explained what "(self-made)" is supposed to mean in your quotes, and even if you did, it still makes no sense at all. Please do stop putting it there. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ...

"I would like to ask you another question: is there a book written on Churchill’s life?"
or
"Would you know if there is a book written on Churchill’s life?"

You could rephrase your original statement that uses the word "bold" to ...

"If I may be so bold, I would like to ask you another question. Is there a book written on Churchill’s life?"

My preference would be the first two as they are both polite using the modal "would".

The third sentence is about as polite as you can get. Be careful using it because it can give certain readers a negative impression precisely because it is extremely polite.

Comment: +1 for "if I may be so bold" which is the standard phrase, and I agree it is a dated expression and might be interpreted negatively by a few.

Comment: It seems my suspicion is confirmed. I shall not be too generous with humility.